# Replacing an element in a NSMutableArray that is multi dimensional?

Tags: objective-c, multidimensional-array, nsmutablearray

I need to be able to replace an object in a multi dimensional NSMutableArray (nested actually) of strings.

I know for a single dimensional array you would do this:

```
[arrayOfTiles replaceObjectAtIndex:4 withObject:@"w"];
```

But not sure how to do this for a multi dimensional array (in this case a nested array).

Here is the array I have setup.

```
NSMutableArray *arrayOfTiles = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity: 5];
[arrayOfTiles insertObject: [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"a", @"b", @"c", @"d",
                      @"e", nil] atIndex: 0];
[arrayOfTiles insertObject: [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"f", @"g", @"h", @"i",
                      @"j", nil] atIndex: 1];
```

How would I accomplish a simple replacement of say (for example) the letter "i" to change it to letter "w" at runtime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make inner array mutable first

```
NSMutableArray *arrayOfTiles = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity: 5];
[arrayOfTiles insertObject: [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects: @"a", @"b", @"c", @"d",
                      @"e", nil] atIndex: 0];
[arrayOfTiles insertObject: [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects: @"f", @"g", @"h", @"i",
                      @"j", nil] atIndex: 1];
```

then you can do this

```
arrayOfTiles[1][3] = @"w";
```

Answer (score 0):

Using modern notation, you can treat nested `NSArray`s just like multi-dimensional C arrays

```
arrayOfTiles[1][3] = @"w";
```